# Javascript arrow function in Bluefish editor

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, arrow-functions, bluefish

Does anyone know how I can invoke the Javascript arrow function in Bluefish editor in Windows 10?

For context, let me explain. I am a beginner trying to learn drag and drop. The videos and mdmwebdocs from developer.mozilla use the arrow function. I am trying to follow along but my coding does not work may because I use the equal sign and the > (look like =>) in Bluefish. The browsers (Firefox and Chrome) do not recognize my version of the arrow.

'''

```
    source.addEventListener('dragstart',(e) => {
    console.log(e);
       })
```

'''
I do not know how to put in the arrow function in Bluefish. I don't know how to convert the code with arrow function into one without the arrow function. I have google this and I  cannot find the answer. I have ran into this problem in the past without resolution. Please, if someone please enlightened me in this matter, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous function

```
source.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have to try it.